# Circle with marker

Tags: android, eclipse, geometry, marker

I wish I could implement in Android what I show in this screenshot:

[image]

The number inside the circle there is no problem for me (simply make some accounts). But I do not know how to put the circle or as putting the marker.

I mean, it's like a speedometer. Then I want depending on the numerical value, the marker is in the position of the circle that matches the numerical value (the value is moved in a range of 0-100, so that the minimum value of the marker in the circle will be 0 or 100, obviously).

I'm a bit stuck with this, any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a circleView for you..just give a try...

**CircleView.java**

```
package com.example.err2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class Circle extends View {

    int radius, number, fontSize = 80;
    Paint myPaint;

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    private void init() {
        Log.d("init", "start");
        myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        // Drawing main crcle
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, 
            getHeight() / 2, 
            radius, myPaint);
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, 
            getHeight() / 2, 
            radius - 10, myPaint);
        // end of main circle

        // drawing text-number
        myPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        myPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);
        myPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        myPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        canvas.drawText(number + "", 
            getWidth() / 2, 
            getHeight() / 2 + fontSize / 3, myPaint);
        // end of drwaing text

        // drawing point on circle boundry
        // findPointLocation();
        double deg = number * 3.6f;
        double radians = Math.toRadians(deg);
        int px = (int) Math.abs(radius * Math.sin(radians));
        int py = (int) Math.abs(radius * Math.cos(radians));
        if (number <= 25) {
            px = -px;
        } else if (number <= 50) {
            px = -px;
            py = -py;
        } else if (number <= 75) {
            py = -py;
        }
        // end od find point
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2 + px, getHeight() / 2 + py, 15,
                myPaint);
        // end of drawing point
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

below given the mainactivity code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Circle circle=(Circle)findViewById(R.id.circle1);
        circle.setRadius(100);
        circle.setNumber(90);
    }
}
```

given below xml code
**XML**

```
<com.example.err2.Circle
    android:id="@+id/circle1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:background="#778888" />
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It shows me this error on the line public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity... The error is:

ActionBarActivity can not be resolved to a type...

Comment: MainActivity extends Activity -this will work...

or youcan put following code it to your MainActivity

        Circle circle=(Circle)findViewById(R.id.circle1);
 circle.setRadius(100);
 circle.setNumber(90);

Comment: it may be due to package naem..pls replace 'com.example.err2' with yourpackage name..

Comment: The package name had already changed, and still shows errors. I also shows many errors in the method Circle ... could get on his project for a closer look? I do not know why your code does not work my me.

Comment: I got it. Something was wrong with eclipse ... I closed and open ... and magic, now it works. 

One thing: 
I'm trying to get the edge of the red circle d eun is a gradient color to another, but can not. I've tried: 

myPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2,getHeight() / 3, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, TileMode.MIRROR));

but the application stops and fails.

Comment: hi..here is the entire project..pls have look..  [link](https://github.com/likhilkt/circle_android)